# Make a div transparent like a blurred mirror

Tags: css, blur

I want to make a div background transparent so i used this css

```
-webkit-filter: blur(1px);
-moz-filter: blur(1px);
-ms-filter: blur(1px);
-o-filter: blur(1px);
filter: blur(1px);
```

also see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUy3W/

I want only the div to be blurred but all the content in that div is also being blurred. How to make only that background div blur and make its content visible like normal text?

any thoughts? please help.

Comment: Use 2 separated div's

Comment: @Itay even I used two divs, problem still persists, please see this fiddle. I would appreciate if you update the fiddle and give me a solution. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 21):

This can now be accomplished with a single line of CSS using the [`backdrop-filter` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) (along with many other [filter effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function)), however [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=css-backdrop-filter) at the time of writing is very poor, so make sure to provide a fallback version for unsupported browsers as well as the `-webkit-` prefixed version for now.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/iAgdW.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.inner {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">my text</div>
</div>
```

The rendered output in supported browsers will look like:

[image: Output]

Comment: As of July 2019, I can only find Safari desktop (and allegedly Safari iOS) to support `backdrop-filter`. In, Chrome and Opera, apparently, they can be activated under an experimental flag which makes them impractical. No sign of compatibility with Firefox.

Comment: @Ramtin Feb 2020: Looks like Chrome now supports this without a flag starting in v76: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backdrop-filter. Firefox still requires a flag.

Comment: @JerryGoyal You can at least enable it for yourself in about:config for testing purposes, which at least shows it's on the roadmap to be implemented some day.

Answer (score 13):

The content can't be inside the blurred div, so use a sibling element instead:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">my text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper::before{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/iAgdW.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
    -moz-filter: blur(4px);
    -ms-filter: blur(4px);
    -o-filter: blur(4px);
    filter: blur(4px);
}
.content{
    position: absolute;
    background-color:red;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8bzf29y/)**

Comment: The image is not hosted anymore. 404 Not Found

Comment: Moz no longer requires a prefix.

Answer (score 3):

For example.

The html

```
<div class="div-Blur">
    <div class="div-inside-blur">
    </div>
</div>
```

The css

```
.div-Blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -moz-filter: blur(1px);
    -ms-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(1px);
    filter: blur(1px);
}
```

edit: try this plse

```
.div-inside-blur { 
    background: blue; 
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
    -ms-filter: blur(0px);
    -o-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px); 
 }
```

Comment: See this sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LUy3W/, I used two separate divs, but of no use. all the content inside div-Blur is blurred.

Comment: @Marinus still the text inside inner div is blurred

Comment: @codehorse your edit didn't work, have a loo at this http://jsfiddle.net/LUy3W/8/